# Share text to whatsapp using intent and get shared person contact details

Tags: android, android-intent

In my app i share text via whatsapp it will work fine. But after share the text successfully need to get shared person or shared group details from onActivityResult in android.

Below code i try.

```
Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
whatsappIntent.setType("text/plain");
whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "The text you wanted to share");
try {
    activity.startActivity(whatsappIntent);
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    ToastHelper.MakeShortText("Whatsapp have not been installed.");
}
```

Comment: first of all, you should start by `startActivityForResult()` and then check if whatsapp actually returns that information as `intent`.

Answer (score 1):

> need to get shared person or shared group details from onActivityResult in android

`ACTION_SEND` does not return a result. You are welcome to call `startActivityForResult()`; it is almost certain that you will not get a result.

Even if for some reason WhatsApp has a buggy `ACTION_SEND` implementation that returns a result, hopefully it does not include "shared person or shared group details", as that would represent a privacy flaw.

If WhatsApp has some dedicated API for working with its Android app or communications service, you could look into using that and see if they offer what you seek.

Comment: you are right. Whatsapp does not provide any dedicated api. It is clear from whatsapp official doc- How to integrate whatsapp with android app? https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/28000012

Comment: If possible find out the no of whatsapp groups text will shared.